How do I build a React app that uses different .css files for different components?
I have a primary css file that provides global styles for most of my website. However, there are 1-2 pages that will use a completely different style.
I want to be able to configure things so that every page in the app uses css file 1, unless I explicitly tell it to use css file 2. If css file 2 is used, NONE of the styling information from css file 1 should appear.
To reiterate: every page should derive styling information from exactly one css file. Which css file is used should default to one file but be able to be set to another file.
This is easy in html so it seems like it should be easy in React.
What I'm seeing is that it tends to "grab" one of the css files and not use the other one. Unless perhaps it's merging styles somehow? It's hard to tell what's going on.

You can use CSS Modules. More information here - https://create-react-app.dev/docs/adding-a-css-modules-stylesheet/

It's not possible to import a CSS file that only applies to a specific component in React. React compiles all your CSS files into one. Alternatively, you can use CSS Modules or SCSS with nested classes to achieve the desired behaviour. I use SCSS as it brings more CSS features and is faster for development.


eg:
React:
<div className="landing"></div>
<div className="footer"></div>

SCSS:
<style>
  .landing {
      .header {}
  }

  .footer {
      .header {}
  }
</style>

